# Usages of "readonly" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, readonly

### Usage 1: a function declares its parameter won't be modified

This usage is very simple: as a contract, the function `doSomething` declares it doesn't mutate the received parameter.

```
interface Counter {
  name: string
  value: number
}

function doSomething(c: Readonly<Counter>) {
  // ...
}

let c = {
  name: "abc",
  value: 123
}
doSomething(c)
// Here we are sure that 'c.name' is "abc" and 'c.value' is '123'
```

### Usage 2: a factory declares that its output cannot be modified

With this code:

```
interface Counter {
  readonly name: string
  readonly value: number
  inc(): number
}

function counterFactory(name: string): Counter {
  let value = 0
  return {
    get name() {
      return name
    },
    get value() {
      return value
    },
    inc() {
      return ++value
    }
  }
}
```

We have here a member `readonly value` that cannot be modified directly from the outside. But a member `inc()` can mutate the value. Also, the member `value` is declared as `readonly` but its value is changing.

I would like to know if this use of `readonly` on the member `value` is a good way to proceed. The syntax is OK. But is this example semantically correct in TypeScript? Is that what the modifier `readonly` is for?

Comment: There is a [specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md) for TypeScript (even if it seems to be obsolete), and many [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) in GitHub that describe new features. An official answer is undoubtedly somewhere. I read the more I can, but I missed many information.

Comment: See also [my similar question on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12#issuecomment-332159281).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword on a property does not ensure that the property value is constant. There's no TypeScript equivalent for that. The only things we can be sure with a readonly property are:

1. Its value can't be changed from the consumer side *→ usage 1.*
2. It can be the inferred type of a get-only property *→ usage 2. Note that, if the `counterFactory` return type is not defined, it is inferred exactly like the `Counter` interface, see (A)  in the code below.*
3. Its value can be set only once and only during the object construction *→ see (B) below.*

Code example:

```js
// (A) Usage 2 using type inference
const counter = counterFactory('foo');
type Counter = typeof counter; // Produce the exact same type as the previous `Counter` interface
counter.value = 10; // [Ts Error] Can not assign to 'value' because it is a constant or read-only property

// (B) Readonly property initialization
// (B1) With an object literal + interface 
const manualCounter: Counter = { name: 'bar', value: 2, inc: () => 0 };
manualCounter.value = 3; // [Ts Error] Can not assign...

// (B2) With a class
class Foo {
  constructor(public name: string, public readonly value: number) { }
  inc() {
    return ++this.value; // [Ts Error] Can not assign...
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('bar', 3);
foo.value = 4; // [Ts Error] Can not assign...

// (C) Circumvent TypeScript
Object.assign(foo, { value: 4 }); // → No error neither in Ts, nor at runtime
```

It's really confusing because it's almost like a constant property! The usage 2 and the case C prove it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Ma question is really on a semantic point of view. An immutable version of `Counter` is another subject. With an immutable object, yes we are sure that `readonly` is convenient. But with a mutable member like in my example?

Comment: `const foo = { get bar() { return 'hello'; } };` has type `{ readonly bar: string; }` because we can't do `foo.bar = '';`. We can mimic this behavior just at TypeScript level (i.e. no more at the transpiled javascript at run-time): having `const foo = { bar: 'hello' } as { readonly bar: string; };`, we can't do `foo.bar = '';` as well. It saves us some code but can be hacked for example with `Object.assign()`.

Comment: @Paleo: your question helped me clarifying my understanding of the `readonly` keyword. I may be more concise with the following explanation: `readonly` is a contract. The object owner of a readonly property only tells that **no consumers can modify the property value** but doesn't tell that _the property value can't change_. You expected the second contract to be true for the usage 2. As for me, I mixed ‘readonlyness’ and immutability.

Comment: > _"a `readonly` property only tells that no consumers can modify it but doesn't tell that its value can't change."_
Yep. Read also these [3 messages on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12#issuecomment-332159281). You could remove all the content of your answer (immutability is not the subject, neither the prefix `_` for the scoped variable `value`), and replace it with a good (maybe short) synthesis. Then I'll validate it.

Comment: In contrast to this explanation, it should be noted that the modifier `readonly` used in a class prevents modification of the property including by members of the class. In fact, at the origin, that's where my misunderstanding comes from. Since a method in a class cannot modify a property `readonly` of that class, what does `readonly` in TS mean and how should it be used?

Answer (score 5):

What creates the confusion is the "double" usage of the word `value' in your factory function.

To clarify, rewrite it this way (please note the _ in front of the `_value` variable):

```
interface Counter {
    readonly name: string
    readonly value: number
    inc(): number
}

function counterFactory(name: string): Counter {
    let _value = 0
    return {
        get name() {
            return name
        },
        get value() {
            return _value
        },
        inc() {
            return ++_value
        }
    }
}
```

1. `_value` is just a local var than you can mutate
2. `get value()` implements the interface definition `readonly value: number`:  `counter.value` **is** readonly

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe the homonym is confusing. However, that wasn't the subject of my issue. Sometimes while programming we write ugly code for any reason (a lack of time or skill) _and because it works!_ Seen from the outside, an instance of `Counter` has a member `value`, this member is tagged as `readonly`, but it mutates. I would like to know if it is a valid way to use the modifier `readonly` or if it is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes it mutates internally (actually `_value` does) but from the outside - which is what the interface describes - it *is*  `readonly`: you can only read it. I think this should not be confused with a `final` property which would be I believe impossible to implement in Javascript (`const` yes, `final` no)