# How can I change a readonly property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to make `readonly` properties (not getters) for users of my class, but I need to update them internally; is there a way to do this and allow to be changed internally? (and make sure TypeScript blocks most attempts to change the value)

*(In my case it's a game engine and getters/setters [functions in general] are a bad option)*

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46400536/3786294

Comment: That post only talks about the semantics of `readonly`, not how to change it.  One post did mention `Object.assign(foo, { value: 4 });` but it is hardly the best way!

Comment: The second usage in the question is an example of how to update a `readonly` property.

Comment: That is for objects, not classes, and is not much better than a getter on an object, except it completely hides the value using closures.

Comment: Aside from the question, a game engine sounds cool! Is it open source? Got a link?

Comment: Hi @trusktr, it's been a journey since I posted that.  I didn't release the code (not even close to ready) but I had something in place for basic particles off GPU buffers (it was a 2D particle game engine). Some videos are here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCalqVOu0oGarxdzXz5dtjNg/videos.  I'm working on a 4X space game now called Planet Outpost, and working on a Voxel engine for it for Unity3D.  Some videos of the game idea - under a different name at the time - is here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC39qcpnrWnh9qvBPzwvO-Kg/videos Follow me at twitter.com/general_p_fault for updates.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are actually 3 ways I know of.  If you have a class like this:

```
class GraphNode {
    readonly _parent: GraphNode;
    add(newNode: GraphNode) { /* ...etc... */ }
}
var node = new GraphNode();
```

In the `add()` function you could do either:

1. `newNode[<any>'_parent'] = this;` - Works, but BAD IDEA. Refactoring will break this.

   **Update:** Seems `newNode['_parent'] = this;` will work just fine now without `<any>` in newer versions of TypeScript, but refactoring will still break it.
2. `(<{_parent: GraphNode}>newNode)._parent = this;` - Better than 1 (not the best), and although refactoring breaks it, at least the compiler will tell you this time (since the type conversion will fail).
3. BEST: Create an INTERNAL interface (used by yourself only):

   ```
   interface IGraphObjectInternal { _parent: GraphNode; }
   class GraphNode implements IGraphObjectInternal {
       readonly _parent: GraphNode;
       add(newNode: GraphNode) { /* ...etc... */ }
   }
   ```

   Now you can just do `(<IGraphObjectInternal>newNode)._parent = this;` and refactoring will also work.  The only caveat is that if you export your class from a namespace (the only reason to use an internal interface IMO) you'll have to export the interface as well. For this reason, I sometimes will use #2 to completely lock down internals where there's only one place using it (and not advertise to the world), but usually #3 if I need to have many properties to work with referenced in many other locations (in case I need to refactor things).

You may notice I didn't talk about getters/setters.  While it is possible to use only a getter and no setter, then update a private variable, TypeScript does not protect you! I can easily do `object['_privateOrProtectedMember'] = whatever` and it will work. It does not work for the `readonly` modifier (which was in the question). Using the `readonly` modifier better locks down my properties (as far as working within the TypeScript compiler is concerned), and because JavaScript doesn't have a `readonly` modifier, I can use various methods to update them with workarounds on the JavaScript side (i.e. at runtime). ;)

**Warning:** As I said, this only works within TypeScript.  In JavaScript people can still modify your properties (unless you use getters only with non-exposed properties).

## Update

Since typescript 2.8 you can now remove the readonly modifiers:

```
type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
```

and also the *optional* modifier:

```
type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] };
```

More here: [Improved control over mapped type modifiers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers)

Comment: Unfortunately the writable method does not work on a private property (it's not in the class interface).

Comment: So what? The question was about readonly properties, not private ones.  For private access I did show above you can use brackets.

Comment: Right. I only pointed it out for future readers. I did not mean to imply that your answer was incorrect.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. :)

Comment: Deeply nested variant:  

`type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? Writeable<T[P]> : T[P] };`

Answer (score 36):

You could make use of the [improved mapped type modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) since Typescript 2.8.

For example, let's say that UI layer (and all others except persistence layer) shall only get a `readonly` version of your domain entity. Persistence layer is a special case, since it somehow must know how to copy all internals into the database.
In order to do so, we don't want to make defensive copies everytime and just use the `readonly` typescript modifier for that purpose.

Your `readonly` entity would be:

```
class Immutable {
    constructor(
        public readonly myProp: string ) {}
}
```

The mutable type of your entity:

```
type Mutable = {
     -readonly [K in keyof Immutable]: Immutable[K] 
}
```

*Note the special `-readonly` syntax to remove the flag* (also works with optionals).

In one limited place (here the persistence layer) we can convert `Immutable` to `Mutable` by doing:

```
let imm = new Immutable("I'm save here")
imm.myProp = "nono doesnt work. and thats good" // error
let mut: Mutable = imm  // you could also "hard" cast here: imm as unknown as Mutable
mut.myProp = "there we go" // imm.myProp value is "there we go"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But, we don't want people to change the mutability of the properties on the outside of the class. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: Some programming languages apply a "cooperative consenting adults" approach; the language features make it clear that cooperative programmers shouldn't do something, but won't stop them from bypassing it when they seem to think to know what they're doing, since the only feet they can shoot into are their own.

Comment: I agree, this is not much different then the old days where someone might cast a struct over some memory block to a known object layout and override the private/readonly properties. While you can do it, you normally shouldn't and take a great risk.  If someone wants to do it, it's up to them to have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 17):

My current solution for TypeScript 3.6.3

```
type Mutable<T> = {
   -readonly [k in keyof T]: T[k];
};

class Item {
  readonly id: string;

  changeId(newId: string) {
    const mutableThis = this as Mutable<Item>;
    mutableThis.id = newId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> The answer posted by OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634877/146656) is the best answer, not this one.
>   Which is just to use an interface and not export it.
>
> ```
> interface IGraphObjectInternal { _parent: GraphNode; }
> export class GraphNode implements IGraphObjectInternal {
>   // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
>   // tslint:disable-next-line:member-access
>   // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
>   public readonly _parent: GraphNode;
>   public add(newNode: GraphNode) {
>     (newNode as IGraphObjectInternal)._parent = this;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> I tried this earlier and had some problem (not sure why, but tried again now and it works just fine.
>
> Leaving the answer here just for the fun of playing with it.

TypeScript provides `readonly` keyword which allows setting value on initialization or in constructor only.

If you want to change the value any time, then what you need is a read-only property, which is known as a "get" property.

Example:

```
class MyClass { 
  private _myValue: WhateverTypeYouWant;

  get myValue() {
    return this._myValue;
  }

  doSomething(inputValue: WhateverTypeYouWant) {
    // Do checks or anything you want.
    this._myValue = inputValue; // Or anything else you decide
  }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that users may still be able to call `myObject['_myValue']` and access the property. TypeScript will not tell them about it in intellisense though, and if they do use your code this way, they are using your library in an unsupported way and shooting themselves in the foot (note that this is client-side code anyway, so the code is available to read).

Check [the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) on how this works.

---

### Update

If you really want to use `readonly` and force it to work, you can do it like this:

```
class Test {
    readonly value = "not changed";

    changeValue() { 
        this["value" as any] = "change from inside";
    }
}
```

But as I mentioned in my comment on this answer, and I show in the [runnable version of this example](http://on.gurustop.net/2y8lOlL), the semantics are the same in the sense that both `private` and `readonly` can be changed from outside if the users really want to.

---

### Update 2

In further comments you bring an interesting scenario, game development, where function call is considered expensive. I cannot validate how expensive property access might be (Which is the recommended path for this generally), but here's the answer I think you are looking for:

If you really really want to do set the `readonly` member, and just want to make sure you have refactoring support, change `this["value" as any] =` to `(this.value as Test['value']) =` (where `Test` here is the class name, and `value` is the property name).

```
class Test {
    // We had to set the type explicitly for this to work
    // Because due to initial `= "not changed"`
    //  `value` property has type `"not changed"` not `string`
    readonly value: string = "not changed";

    changeValue() { 
        (this.value as Test['value']) = "change from inside";
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

const test = new Test();

test.changeValue();

(test.value as Test['value']) = 'change from outside';
alert(test.value);
```

[Runnable Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20We%20had%20to%20set%20the%20type%20explicitly%20for%20this%20to%20work%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Because%20due%20to%20initial%20%60%3D%20%22not%20changed%22%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%60value%60%20property%20has%20type%20%60%22not%20changed%22%60%20not%20%60string%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20value%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22not%20changed%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20changeValue()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(this.value%20as%20Test%5B'value'%5D)%20%3D%20%22change%20from%20inside%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(this.value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atest.changeValue()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A(test.value%20as%20Test%5B'value'%5D)%20%3D%20'change%20from%20outside'%3B%0D%0Aalert(test.value)%3B)

---

### Update 3

Although the syntax `(this.value as Test['value']) =` works in official TypeScript playground, as proven by the link at the end of Update 2 in this answer, it doesn't work in VS Code (and maybe other TS environments).

You need to change it to `this['value' as Test['value']] =` (where, again, `Test` is a class name and `value` is a property name).

The working code becomes:

```
class Test {
  // We had to set the type explicitly for this to work
  // Because due to initial `= "not changed"`
  //  `value` property has type `"not changed"` not `string`
  readonly value: string = "not changed";

  changeValue() {
    this['value' as Test['value']] = "change from inside";
    alert(this.value);
  }
}

const test = new Test();

test.changeValue();

test['value' as Test['value']] = 'change from outside';
alert(test.value);
```

[Runnable Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20We%20had%20to%20set%20the%20type%20explicitly%20for%20this%20to%20work%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Because%20due%20to%20initial%20%60%3D%20%22not%20changed%22%60%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%60value%60%20property%20has%20type%20%60%22not%20changed%22%60%20not%20%60string%60%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20value%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22not%20changed%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20changeValue()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this%5B'value'%20as%20Test%5B'value'%5D%5D%20%3D%20%22change%20from%20inside%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(this.value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atest.changeValue()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atest%5B'value'%20as%20Test%5B'value'%5D%5D%20%3D%20'change%20from%20outside'%3B%0D%0Aalert(test.value)%3B)

#### Limited Refactoring

Since refactoring is the reason for asking the question I have to mention that besides being ugly, the workaround here offers only limited refactoring support.

That means, if you misspell property name (`value` in the sample) in any part of the assignment `this['value' as Test['value']] = ...`, TypeScript will give you a compile time error.

The problem though is, at least in VS Code in my quick test, when you rename the property (from `value` in the sample to anything else), TypeScript / VS Code doesn't update the references to it that are implemented using this workaround.

It still gives you a compile time error, which is better than leaving invalid code without errors, but you'd want it to rename the property for you too.

Luckily having to do this with a string replace (of `['value' as Test['value']]` in the sample) seems to be generally safe from false matches, but still, it's silly, and less than desired, but I think this is as far as this gets.

Comment: Sorry, not good enough.  I already commented on that. `var o = new MyClass(); o['_myValue'] = whatevertheuserwants;` still works. With `readonly` it does not.

Comment: You are not supposed to change `readonly` after initialization. You "can" do it, but so can any user from outside too, just like `private`. Here's an example (Click "Run" on top right to see in action): http://on.gurustop.net/2y8lOlL

Comment: Incorrect, other API users should not change it.  There's no reason in TS that internal routines cannot - it is not constant; there's a `const` modifier that exist for that reason.  For that matter I can put `readonly` in any interface to show get-only properties (where values CAN change). Also, you virtually just posted an update saying what I already said. lol ;)  This will break upon refactoring the code, so not advised.

Comment: Again, it can be changed from outside. It should not be changed from outside (and TS tried to make it difficult to do for this reason). The "right" answer for this in terms of semantics is private member with a get property.

Comment: I know it can still be changed in JS. ;)  The idea is hoping other users are using my API to build TypeScript apps, and keeping a bit more control (via the TS compiler) on what can be changed.

Comment: Not the "right answer" if you're creating a game engine where high speed is required.  Properties (function calls in general) are not allowed as it will slow everything down. Properties should be read/updated directly on objects, and TS doesn't help lock down these for 3rd party developers, so in the field of game development it is never a good idea, and bad design. TS always had a narrow focus towards business use only, with little love for high speed requirements, and the "best practises" are usually really bad.

Comment: If I  can create a `readonly` getter property that can change, there's no excuse for TypeScript to lock down properties marked with `readonly` within the class itself (outside the constructor). TypeScript is the one breaking consistency in such cases.

Comment: Interesting scenario. I've changed my code to support refactoring in Update 2 to support refactoring. Check it out and tell me whether it meets your requirement (although I admit it's a bit ugly).

Comment: It's better, but `Test['value']` will never refactor, so it's the same as my point # 2. ;)

Comment: No it's not the same. If you change `'value'` to anything else in `Test['value']`, Typescript will give you an error. Try it.

Comment: I added Update 3 about using this in VS Code and about refactoring support.

Comment: It is the same as `(<{_parent: GraphNode}>newNode)._parent = this;`.  If I change `_parent: GraphNode` it also fails.  You're just doing the same thing a different way. ;)  Also in both cases the compiler will catch it (give an error) if it gets refactored.

Comment: BTW - you are refactoring in the playground. In Visual Studio 2017 it does not work. In fact, the code in my previous comment refactors same as yours. ;)

Comment: It's exported for a reason! lol ;)  It's to allow other "internal" classes to access/update the properties (for example, a graph parent setting 'parent' on a child object). It's true only if the class is the only one changing it. Also, thanks for trying to find out other ideas. ;)

Comment: In fact I tried the interface before and I don't remember what error I got, but I looked at your answer today and tried it again. It worked! And if you do the renaming from the interface itself, it also updates everywhere, so, I'd say mark your interface answer as the correct answer. I added a note about it to the top of my answer.

Comment: You HAVE to export it if you implement it in your class! That was the whole point - to support refactoring. In fact, TS gives an error otherwise (a public class implementing a private interface). `State Error TS4019 (TS) Implements clause of exported class 'TextClass' has or is using private name 'IInternalTest'.`

Comment: I just created a new project with typescript@2.5.3 and tslint@5.7.0, and worked just fine with no errors related to access modifiers in VS Code or `tsc`. That's with the default `tsconfig.json` generated from `tsc --init` and `tslint.json` generated from `tslint --init`.

Comment: The only errors I saw were unrelated tslint errors on `_parent` property, disabled as follows: `// tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name`, `// tslint:disable-next-line:member-access`, and `// tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name`

Comment: The `member-access` tslint error is not related, it's just that default tslint asks for explicitly mentioning `public` or `private`.

Comment: I have a .Net Core project and TS 2.5 and a private interface for a public class doesn't work in VS 2017 (at least not yet, I'll keep an eye on it).

Answer (score 7):

Here's the solution I like best (using a tip courtesy of James Wilkins). My thought is that write access should be only allowed within the class, hence making the getter private.

```
type Writable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] }; 

class TestModel {
  readonly val: number;

  setVal(value: number) {
    this.asWriteable.val = value;
  }

  // use this.asWriteable.* to write to readonly fields
  private get asWriteable(): Writable<TestModel> {
    return this as Writable<TestModel>;
  }
}
```

Comment: While it works, I would not recommend it.  It breaks any ability to refactor your code.  There is already a supported solution that works better: 
`class TestModel {
    readonly val: number;
  
    setVal(value: number) {
      (<Writeable<TestModel>>this).val = value;
    }
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For whatever reason that didn't compile and I didn't see an import for `Writeable` (except an unrelated stream class), but this works:
` type Writable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

type WriteableTestModel = Writable<TestModel>;

class TestModel {
  readonly val: number;
  setVal(value: number) {
    (this as WriteableTestModel).val = value;
`code`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it may not be included by default.  It was in the docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html (they really should think about adding it, if not done so already)