# How to mock API functions inside saga with jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, redux-saga

I want to mock API functions inside my saga tests but I couldn't because typescript complains that it's a read-only property. Here's my code.

```
// src/api/todos.ts
import axios from './utils/axios'
import { handleError } from './error'

export const fetchTodosApi = async () => {
   return axios.get(`/todos/`).catch(handleError)
}
```

I have `index.ts` that exports all API functions like so:

```
export { fetchTodosApi } from './todos'
```

Then my test saga:

```
// src/tests/fetchTodos
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga'
import { fetchTodos } from 'sagas'
import * as api from 'api'

describe('testing fetchTodosApi ', () => {
   it('is able to fetch todos', async () => {
      const dispatchedActions: Array<any> = []
      api.fetchTodosApi = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))

      const fakeStore: any = {
         dispatch: (action: any) => dispatchedActions.push(action),
         getState: () => state,
      }

      await runSaga(fakeStore, fetchTodos, action).toPromise()

      expect(dispatchedActions[0].todos).toEqual({})
   })
})
```

The problem is I can't assign `api.fetchTodosApi` with a mock function cos it's a read-only property as per Typescript. If I change how api functions are exported from `index.ts` in the api dir to something like:

```
import { fetchTodosApi } from './todos'
const api = { fetchTodosApi }
export default api
```

I can assign a mock function to `api.fetchTodosApi` but it retains its original definition, not the definition from the mock function and it feels hackish. How do I get around this? It works with vanilla Javascript as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9f97afxa9A

Comment: Or perhaps there's another way to do this. Please let me know.

Comment: have you tried `// @ts-ignore - readonly`? see also [How can I change a readonly property in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634876/how-can-i-change-a-readonly-property-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to spy on the read-only property.
And you can do a mockImplementation resolving the promise on the created spy object.

```
let mockData = []; // sample data
const spy = jest.spyOn(api, 'fetchTodosApi');
spy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jest.mock` and mock the module like it is in the documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules). For mock store, you can look on [this](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store) package